# It saves you endless agony - Correct?

Tags: grammar, clauses, construction

My sentence reads:

> It may not save you bucks, but, it surely saves you endless agony.

Is this correct? Or, do you suggest any alterations?

Comment: It's correct, it's jaunty, and I like it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"It may not save you money, but it will surely save you endless agony," she said, encouraging her friend to pay a little more for a sharp razor rather than save a little on a dull one.